# why does a call of a function with set parameters does not generate the expected output?

Tags: c, xcode

In the following code, when I debugged it, the first call function (mazesentence(0, 0, 1, 0);) also went to the if(before == 1 ), but 'before' is clearly a zero. Why is it entering in that location? I would imagine, i have my braces incorrectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mazesentence(int little, int twist, int twisting, int before)
{    
    
    
    if(little == 0 && twist == 0 && twisting == 1)
    {
        if(before == 0)
        {
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1)
                printf("twisting ");
            printf("little ");
            printf("maze of ");
        }
        if(before == 1)
            printf("little ");
        {
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1)
                printf("twisting ");
                printf("maze of");
        }
        
    }
    return;
}

int main( )
{
    mazesentence(0, 0, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 1, 1);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 0, 1);
    mazesentence(0, 1, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 1, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 0, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 0, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 1, 1);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 0, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You appear to have some mismatched braces after `if(before == 1)` unless you meant for only that first line after the if to be conditional. Perhaps after `else if(twisting == 1)` too unless that's just an indentation error. If you always use braces, even for 1 line conditionals you lessen the likeliness of this problem because it is much more obvious.

Comment: Your statement `if(before == 1)` has a `printf` after it (not a brace) so the if applies only to that one statement.  The braces that follow are NOT part of the if, even though it looks like you intended them to be from your indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your braces are indeed incorrect. Looking at the problem conditional:

```
        if(before == 1)
            printf("little ");
        {
```

The way this is, the `if` only guards the `printf("little ")`. That is then is followed by a code block that executes unconditionally.

It should be this to guard the entire block:

```
        if(before == 1)
        {
            printf("little ");
```